# How to recover recently deleted API from Azure APIM?

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there any way to restore the deleted API on Azure APIM? The API was deleted recently (3 days back).

We have azure APIM instance backup taken daily, but we want to avoid complete instance restore as APIM service has 100+ APIs. Can we restore a single API from backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot recover a deleted API from the Azure API management instance.

As Per the current [Azure documentation,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/soft-delete) we can recover a soft-delete API Management Instance & currently this feature is in preview.

It  depends  on how you delete an API Management instance, the instance is either soft-deleted and recoverable during a retention period, or it's permanently deleted:

- When you use the Azure portal or REST API version  `2020-06-01-preview`  or later to delete an API Management instance, it's  **soft-deleted**.
- An API Management instance deleted using a REST API version before  `2020-06-01-preview`  is  **permanently deleted**.
- An API Management instance deleted using API Management commands in Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI is  **permanently deleted**..